# Logarithmic simplification

Tags: logarithms

I don't understand the last simplification $9^{\log n} = n^{\log 9}$:
$$3^{\log(n^2)} = 3^{2\log n} = 9^{\log n} = n^{\log 9}$$
Can someone please show me how they did it? Is there a rule that I have missed?

Comment: Simple :take logarithm on both sides of the simplification equation and you get basically the same thing ;;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a^b=c^{b(\log a)}$, where $c$ is the base of $\log$, we have that
$$9^{\log n} = c^{\log n\cdot( \log 9)}=c^{\log 9\cdot( \log n)}=n^{\log 9}.$$

Comment: Doesn't $log$ have a base of 2?

Comment: @Samu  If your $\log$ has base $2$ then replace $c$ with $2$. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Take logarithms. For LHR we have

$$
\log(9^{\log n})=\log n \log 9
$$
do the same for RHR